# How can Print from portal row in filemaker

Tags: filemaker

As mentioned on Topic I would like to print from select the portal row. In fact, the first row in the portal can print but the second or third row can't print please find below my script print

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use the `Go to Related Record[]` script step to go to the record in the selected row. If you want, you can do this in a new window (like your script does). Note that this step also allows you to select the layout. Note also that when printing, you can select to print the current record only.

Comment: still Problem I following to use go to Record but same issue

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "same issue". Describe exactly what you did and what was the result.